# Keep all the site under SSL excepet two subfolders, without .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ssl

I would like to know if is possible to keep all the site under ssl except two sub folders that works as a endpoint for external calls with apache.

I've my site (www.example.com) that user can see only trought `https` and I would like to keep `example.com/subfolder1` and `example.com/subfolder2` reachable also trough the normal `http` protocol. Is it possibile? 
This is the .conf file of apache.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm trying to avoid the use of the .htaccess file, is it possibile? Thanks to all!

Comment: Anything you can do in `.htaccess` you can do in the Apache `.conf`.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks, I didn't know that (I'm feeling a little embarrassed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Rewrite (instead of a Redirect) so you can set a condition. Maybe like this:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(subfolder1|subfolder2)/? [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

You have to enable the rewrite module for that too:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Comment: Is it allowed to use RewriteRule for redirect? I thought I had read that it was not recommended. Anyway thank you, right now I'm going with your solution.
EDIT: nevermind, I remembered it wrong. It's not recommended to use it in the .htaccess.